# Hit a button within the browser that would un-focus the browser then focus a different application?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, applescript

Is that possible using AppleScript on macOS or VBScript on Windows? Desktop only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It would involve an applescript that would be called by clicking a hyperlink in the web page. You can find additional information [here](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/)

Basically, your Applescript would be responsible for changing the front application. The Applescript would be triggered by the link in the website.

**Note :**
The user has to "approve" the running of the script initially, but after that, it's capable of running once the link is clicked without additional user input.